# Snowflake Connection & Setup

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-synapse

I'm working with a client to manage an integration with their closed system CRM to their email platform (called MYGuestList) and BI reporting platform (Tableau).

Our CRM is doing to push a data replication to a SQL server (Microsoft Azure). We've been interested to bring Snowflake into the tech stack to house all data points (Google Analytics, email marketing efforts, media etc.) to produce this "single customer view" and manage our integrations.

I'm a bit lost as to what we do next (I can't seem to reach out to Snowflake for any sort of support) and would love any guidance on the following questions:

- How do I go about connecting our Azure server (once set up) to Snowflake?

  - How might I suggest our third party developers look to integrate with our data points in Snowflake?
  - Do I need to purchase a third party connector (FiveTran/Stitch) to ETL data from Google Analytics?

Thank you in advance for your help with this very big newbie trying to solve this problem for my client!

Kate

Comment: I'm also trying to get any understanding of what the cost might look like. With multiple connections and calls - is this likely to get quite expensive?

Answer (score 0):

You have this 3 options to load data:

- Use some ETL tool, or own eg Python app to get data from source system and insert it into Snowflake (directly or to PUT file to Snowflake stage)
- extract data as csv to cloud directory or Snowflake stage, and use bulk load (COPY INTO) to load it
- you may use PIPE to automaticaly load data from files inserted like in second option

Comment: The only thing that I would add is that the cost would depend on the storage and compute size of GA, email and media. Each of those are structured a bit differently and I only know of the connector in the Fivetran libraryhttps://fivetran.com/directory/google-analytics/snowflake-data-warehouse . :I would check out the professional services options a d partner network to help you get set up and consult